# Saga that depend on events from the past

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, saga

I have a question how to deal with a saga where the decision making
depends on an event that was published before the saga was created.

Here is an example to illustrate my issue:

Imagine I have a CustomerAR and a OrderAR. When the customerAR is
created a validation process starts, the result of that process is the
amount of an order that the customer is free to spend without special
authorization. I will not go into detail about this process because
it's out of context. When the amount is calculated a command is sent
to the the CustomerAR with the calculated amount and the CustomerAR
publishes an event (CustomerMaxOrderAmountEvent) with that value. So
far so good.

Then a few weeks later the customer places an order. The OrderAR is
created and starts my OrderSaga. The saga waits until the order is
created completely and then has to make a decision if it needs to send
an AutorizationCommand for that order. To make that decision it has to
know if the CustomerMaxOrderAmountEvent is published and the value of
the amount. Normally the OrderSaga will also subscribe to the
CustomerMaxOrderAmountEvent, but the problem is this event will never
occur because it already did in the past.

How should I deal with this. Should I query the read model to know the
value, should I send a command to get the value, should I make a
reference to the CustomerAR, should I replay all historic events in
the saga so he knows the history already.

**UPDATE**

Please note that it's about the concept not about this concrete example. The example is pure for clarification of the problem: "2 non related aggregate roots that are not part of the same bounded context."

Thankful for help.

Melvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for simpler solution - just add this information (for example in a form of `HasCustomerReachedMaxOrderAmount`) to the event that starts the Saga.

The second option I'd choose is to prepare a read-model designed to be used with the Sagas and query data from there, but I'd gather all the required information even before the saga is started. This enrichment could be performed by a handler to the original event raised by AR as this is not something that is part of Aggregate/Bounded Context.

In most cases however basing on data passed with events is sufficient due to the fact that Sagas should contain business logic only in form of process. This very often means that you  might end up with more then one Saga (to follow your example `OrderSaga` and `OrderWithMaxAmountSaga`).

All that said, considering the sample scenario you've provided, I think that decision whether order requires authorization or not should rather be part of your domain itself and passed while starting saga.

I'd model this scenario like this - `CustomerAR` calculates max amount; customer places an order -> `OrderAR` is created *with* the information about max amount for this customer, `Order` verifies if it needs additional authorization -> `Saga` get started. The point is that information about max amount is important for both `CustomerAR` (where it can change) and `OrderAR` (where it's immutable).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I agree this is a possible solution for this specific situation. But what about the situation when the two aggregate roots are not part of the same Bounded Context or don't have an direct relation. First of all it would be impossible, but also would we want to put irrelevant data in the events because some saga needs the data. According to DDD my AR should not be considered by who listens or handles the events. It should provide that data that is relevant to the event not to the handlers of the event.

Comment: I agree with your second option. This is actually what I'm doing right now, but somehow is doesn't feel right, but I could be wrong. I also agree on the fact that the decision must me made based on the data in the events but that what I want. Only the event has been published in the past. I can't exactly follow your point about multiple sagas and how this will be helpful in this situation. I still have to make the decision based on the event that doesn't contain the data I need to make that decision. I hope you can clear that last point up for me.

Comment: Thanks I understand what you mean now, and I agree this could be the solution for this specific situation, but I'm interested in the concept how to handle this in general. I updated my question to make that more clear. Hope you have any thought about it.

Comment: In my opinion, there is no general in DDD, every solution is tightly coupled with business domain. That said, if Saga should nor rely on an event that has happened in the past - if it does then this means that this event should have started the Saga in the first place. That of course may drive changes in model to be introduced, just like I described in my answer. That's my opinion on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting to dabble with DDD and I don't intend to repeat anything that kstaurch said, but here are some thoughts I had looking at your scenario:

1. What about making the max order amount part of the billing information?  That has to be gotten somewhere and I'm sure you take care of the condition where payment processing is denied.
2. What if the saga *always* sends the authorization command, but it's the authorization part that handles the max order screen?  If you're saying "If the amount is over $X then get authorization", maybe your business model also thinks of it as "If it's under $X, auto-approve."  The benefit is that *all* approval considerations (including whether to get approval) can be moved to an approval entity or saga.